# change of variables for hyperbolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the PDE $U_{xx}+2U_{xy}-3U_{yy}+2U_x+6u_y = 0$;

I wish to convert the PDE to canonical form, by a change of variables.

I have computed the discriminant as positive, which tells me that the PDE is hyperbolic, so I think that the wave equation is the canonical form.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

Considering only tne main terms $AU_{xx}+BU_{xy}+CU_{yy}$ of the hyperbolic PDE, with $A=1\:,\:B=2\:,\:C=-3$, solving for $r$ the equation $Ar^2+Br+C=0$  gives two roots $r_1=1$ and $r_2=-3$

This draw to the change of variables 
$\begin{cases}
s=1\:x+y \\
t=-3\:x+y
\end{cases}$

This will lead to the canonical form, simple to integrate later on.

It should be too long to explain here the method of characteristics for the choice of the change of variables. This can be found in many books or papers.